# Apply Lazy loading/Infinite scroll on array data

Tags: multisite, infinite-scroll

In my website front page, I am running a some code which is getting posts belongs to "Global" category from all of it's subsite. Then I am applying the `usort()` method to sort the post as per the date. Then I am showing.

Now I faced the problem, as the post amount grows day by day, it will slower the page loading time. So I need to apply a `load more/lazy loading/Infinite scroll` to load data, which may increase page load time. Below is my code.

```
$blogs = wp_get_sites();
$postType = array('event', 'ohmama');
$globalPosts = array();
foreach($blogs as $blog) {
    switch_to_blog($blog['blog_id']);
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => array('event', 'post'),
        'category'           => get_cat_ID('Global')
    );
    $results = get_posts($args);
    foreach($results as $result1) {
        $result1->blog_id = $blog['blog_id'];
        $globalPosts[] = $result1;
    }
    restore_current_blog();
}
function orderDate ($a, $b) {
    $aTime = strtotime($a->post_date);
    $bTime = strtotime($b->post_date);
    if ($aTime == $bTime) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($aTime > $bTime) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($globalPosts, 'orderDate');
```

After Applying `usort()` to the `$globalPosts` I need to apply `load more/lazy loading/Infinite scroll` to do my work.

I need some suggestion. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: I think you have already retrieved all the data and sorted it. Lazy loading may help you but in that case you should not load all the data in array.

Comment: Without getting all the data to a single array how to apply the sort by date function?

Comment: Why don't you use shortcodes to display posts ordered by date. There is a plugin I know called infinite scroll. It requires paginate content.

Comment: But infinite scroll will not bring post from different site. As well as I am applying masonry and isotope after appending the posts.